# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'

I am getting this error constantly. Whenever I create a project using maven it starts displaying this error. I have even mentioned the 'maven-war-plugin' under plugin tag and then updated and refreshed the project as well.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myfirstmvcapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworldabc</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>helloworldabc Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
    <finalName>helloworldabc</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Use `https` for the location of the xsd not `http`.

Comment: Please don't display your code as an image. No-one wants to retype a long URL copied manually from an image.

Comment: @MichaelKay I have edited the question and removed the image, instead I added the code. I am Actually new here so I barely knew how this worked

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank You Sir, Your solution has helped get rid of this error

Comment: And providing the error message would be helpful too :)

Comment: @barti_ddu Okay

Comment: If I paste your XML into Oxygen and click "validate", it validates just fine (and shows errors if I make it deliberately invalid). So the problem is something to do with the way you are running the validation (which you haven't said anything about). You say "it starts displaying this error", but what is "it"?

Comment: By 'it' I meant IDE. I wanted to create a simple project using with MVC functionality, I chose maven and selected archetype as 'webapp'. after the project and the files in it were successfully loaded, an error blip appeared on 'pom.xml'. Inside pom.xml, the IDE was indicating the error at the first line where the '<Project>' tag starts.
when you hover on the red blip at line one(where it is indicating the error) it displays a tooltip message:

error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have Found the Solution to this problem, Thanks to @M.Deinum who commented the solution below the question.

All I did was add https to the link in the tag, instead of http.

here is the previous code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myfirstmvcapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworldabc</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>helloworldabc Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
    <finalName>helloworldabc</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the lastest code, all that is needed is to add https instead of http to the xsd link in the last link of project tag.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myfirstmvcapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworldabc</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>helloworldabc Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
    <finalName>helloworldabc</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You would think `mvn tidy:pom` wouldn't break perfectly-good https links, but it does.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problems after replacing the HTTP with HTTPS.

Comment: weird... i have the opposite problem -- but only in Eclipse (Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043) ... i encounter the same error message and google search lead me to this answer... mine was already with https then i tried changing https to http and it worked... (from command line mvn does not give error whether http or https)

Comment: exact same thing for me with Eclipse same Version an Build id in Linux Mint 20.3. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: For me it was opposite Eclipse Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0) Build id: 20231201-2043 , change existing https to http

Answer (score 16):

I had to use **https** for all of them  i.e.

```
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

for the warning to go away in VSCode.

Comment: I too had to add https to all of them to get the error to go away

Comment: It works for eclipse too, thanks

Answer (score 7):

As there is no such issue like replacing http with https in Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0), and using Java version: 17.0.8.1

You need to **force download** https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd; for that simply hover the mouse on this link and click download.

Comment: this thing worked for me